# How to make an excel cell automatically copy from another cell(eg. a name) at a click of a button

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to make a an excel cell copy from another cell in the same document but different page at a click of a button.   I want it to copy a name from another cell not a number

Comment: Do you actually want it to wait for you to click something, or is the default behaviour of updating automatically sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

For the 'click of a button' part you'd need to use VBA.  Simple exmaple:

1. Create a new spreadsheet
2. Press Alt-F11 to get the VBA editor up
3. Double-click the `ThisWorkbook` entry in the `VBAProject` tree on the left; this should give you a blank editor
4. Paste in the code at the bottom of this post
5. Make sure the Developer tab is turned on; instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx)
6. Add a button; instructions [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-a-button-and-assign-a-macro-to-it-in-a-worksheet-HP010236676.aspx#BMadd_or_edit_a_button_%28forms_toolbar%29)

Code for point (4) above: note that this copies from cell B1 to cell A1.  You can replace those with any cell values, of course, but also with a name rather than a cell address.  For example, if you have a named cell of "MyVal", you'd put "MyVal" in the place of "B1" or "A1".

```
Sub CopyValue()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B1")
End Sub
```